# Is there any way to add emergency contact number on dashboard in android programmatically?

Tags: android, locking, phone-call, unlock

I want to implement a feature in an application.User can add any emergency number list on dashboard.The purpose of that feature is so that if there is an emergency you can dial an emergency number (911) without having to unlock the phone.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void phoneCall()
{
 String phoneCallUri = "tel:92";
 Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
 startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
}
```